# vba For Loop is pasting lines with blanks rows inbetween

Tags: vba, for-loop, copy-paste

I am trying to loop through rows pulling every 100th line and then pasting that into the active workbook. For some reason that I can't figure out, the copy seems to work fine, but the paste, where is should be pasting into the Range(E2:V2), it is pasting into E3:V3, and then everytime it goes through the for loop it skips another line. So instead of pasting into E2:V2, it goes E3:V3, then E5:V5.

```
  AwbRownum = 2        
        For Rownum = 2 To wb.Sheets("Export").Range("A" & lastRowwb) Step 100
            Debug.Print "Rownum: " & Rownum
            buffer = wb.Sheets("Export").Range("A" & Rownum, "R" & Rownum).Value
            Awb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & AwbRownum, "V" & AwbRownum).Rows(AwbRownum).Value = buffer
            Debug.Print "AwbRownum = " & AwbRownum

            AwbRownum = AwbRownum + 1

        Next Rownum
```

Comment: I think it's related to the way you find your last row for each workbook, and how you set your `Rownum` and `Rownum`. Can you post the rest of your code ? (the relevant part)

Comment: This `wb.Sheets("Export").Range("A" & lastRowwb)` is returning the value in the column A where the row = lastrowwb.  I believe you just want to use `lastRowwb` : `For Rownum = 2 To lastRowwb Step 100`

Comment: Also thanks Scott Craner, I didn't notice I was doing that since it worked, but I updated that in the code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to put the `buffer` array to a Range in `Awb.Sheets("Sheet1")`, so you don't need the `Rows(AwbRownum)` at the end.

Just change your line :

```
Awb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & AwbRownum, "V" & AwbRownum).Rows(AwbRownum).Value = buffer
```

to:

```
Awb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & AwbRownum, "V" & AwbRownum).Value = buffer
```

Answer (score 0):

when you write:

```
Awb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & AwbRownum, "V" & AwbRownum).Rows(AwbRownum).Value = buffer
```

`.Rows(AwbRownum)` is an offset of the range defined by `Awb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & AwbRownum, "V" & AwbRownum)`.